# How to break out of a List<T>.ForEach() loop from within an if statement in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

I would like to skip an iteration of a `List<T>.ForEach()` loop from within an `if` statement.

I have the code:

```
        instructions.ForEach(delegate(Instruction inst)
        {                
            if (!File.Exists(inst.file))
            {
                continue; // Jump to next iteration
            }

            Console.WriteLine(inst.file);
        });
```

However the compiler states there is nothing to jump out from (presumably as it seems to take the if block as the enclosing block?).

Is there anyway to do the above? Something like `parentblock.continue;` etc.

Thanks

Comment: whats is wrong with for loop or foreach?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but why not just make it a positive check and move your logic inside the if? `if (File.Exists){do stuff}` instead of if not continue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `return` statement instead of `continue`.  Remember that by using the ForEach extension method, you are executing a function for each item, the body of which is specified between { and }.  By exiting the function it will just continue with the next value from the list.

Comment: Rather than returning if it doesn't exist why not just print it if it does exist.

Answer (score 5):

`ForEach` in this case is just a method executing a delegate for every item in the list. It is not a looping control structure so `continue` cannot appear there. Rewrite it as a normal `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var inst in instructions) {
    if (!File.Exists(inst.file))
    {
        continue; // Jump to next iteration
    }

    Console.WriteLine(inst.file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, am trying to use the original approach as it's outside my comfort zone and a good learning curve.

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime It is [not considered a good practice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) by many experts to begin with.  To be honest, I would discourage you from using it at all.  Rather than looking for ways to do simple things in hard ways, look for ways to do hard things in simple ways.

Answer (score 5):

Use LINQ's Where clause to apply the predicate from the onset

```
foreach(Instruction inst in instructions.Where(i => File.Exists(i.file))){
    Console.WriteLine(inst.file);
}
```

Comment: Heh, nice, but shouldn't be the solution the OP picks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The delegate that is sent to the ForEach function will run once per item in the instructions list. For it to skip one item just return from the delegate function.

```
    instructions.ForEach(delegate(Instruction inst)
    {                
        if (!File.Exists(inst.file))
        {
            return; // Jump to next iteration
        }

        Console.WriteLine(inst.file);
    });
```